# Process variable numbers of lines in a Record using mapreduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have a file which I need to process which contains records which contains variable number of lines.

For example I have the following file:-

**100,abc,123
101,abc,123
120,abc,123**
100,abc,123
111,abc,123
123,abc,123
120,abc,123
**100,abc,123
111,abc,123
120,abc,123**
100,abc,123
114,abc,123
120,abc,123

**So bold and non-bold above show each record.**
So each of the record as you can see from above starts with 100 and ends with 120.But each of the record contains variable number of lines like 3 or 4 etc. Now I know this could be solved using custom input format and custom record reader where I can reuse linerecordreader to handle variable lines. But with that approach the problem is that if the record(starting with 100 line and ending with 120) is itself too large to contain in map as single record.So in such cases this will fail. So I need some better solution by which this could be solved using default inputformat and recordreader and doing something in mapper or reducer etc. More than one job is also welcome if the problem could be solved somehow.

Comment: So, can you share what you have tried so far?